# What is the advantage of setting a character column as VARCHAR(32) over VARCHAR(255)

Tags: mysql, database-design, varchar, chart

What is the advantage of setting a database column `VARCHAR(32)` over `VARCHAR(255)` even though the two of them consume 2-byte memory?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably defaulted to `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4), in which case `(255)` would need 2 bytes for the length.

But the real problem is with temp tables (pre-8.0):  If the `SELECT` is so complex that it needs to generate a temp table (eg, for sorting), it will try first to use a `MEMORY` table.  In doing so, it will turn `VARCHARs` into `CHARs`, thereby taking 765 bytes (if utf8).  If, in doing so, this (and other actions) take too much space, it will switch to the slower `MyISAM` for the temp table.  See the status value `Created_tmp_disk_tables`.

For SSN, country_code, zip, etc, explicitly say `CHARACTER SET ascii` (or latin1).  This will avoid extra bloat for the charset.

For fixed-length columns, use `CHAR`, not `VARCHAR`.  So, if this is a US SSN, shouldn't it be

```
SSN CHAR(11) CHARACTER SET ascii  COMMENT 'example: "123-45-6789"'
```

In spite of all that, the performance difference will be minor.

More important in the serious legal implications (in the US) if your computer is hacked into, and you lose sensitive info such as SSNs.  The cost of such a breach could bankrupt your fledgling business.  And no, simply encryption won't suffice -- think about how easy the hacker can find the encryption key.